# Cosmos bulk insert too slow

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert 2 million records as fast as possible. Right now it takes about a day to do so, and this unacceptable. I am using a stored procedure and python to do the bulk insert but I am finding this to be a terrible option as there is a limit to the document size and the stored procedure runtime. Any suggestions on how I can speed this up?

Comment: By Bulk you mean that you are just sending lots of documents through Stored Procedure calls? Why are you using Stored Procedures and just not point operations?

Comment: For real Bulk support, there are alternatives in the [.NET SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/) and [Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java), but no Python support yet.

Comment: Make sure you are putting properties you will never query by in the ExcludedPaths in your index policy. You can also try just turning off indexing, ingesting all your data and then turn it back on.

Comment: You mentioned a limit to document size. Documents are limited to 2MB, whether you try inserting them directly via discrete calls, or via bulk operation within a Stored Procedure. Perhaps you could elaborate on that a bit? For instance, are you talking about a limit to how much data you can send to the Stored Procedure? Also: where is the source data coming from: another database? A structured file (like CSV)? Somewhere else? Please edit your question to provide more specific details, including how you built your stored procedure. Without specifics, it's difficult to figure out the bottleneck.